# Navigation Property Eagerly loading when Lazy Loading is turned on

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

Looks like my  navigation property is eagerly loading when Lazy loading is turned on. 
I have a DBContext setup like this

```
public class BBBankContext : DbContext
{
    public BBBankContext(DbContextOptions<BBBankContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>(b =>
        {
            b.HasData(new Account
            {
                Id = "37846734-172e-4149-8cec-6f43d1eb3f60",
                AccountNumber = "0001-1001",
                AccountTitle = "Raas Masood",
                CurrentBalance = 2342.34,
                Email = "raasmasood@hotmail.com",
                PhoneNumber = "6096647000",
                AccountStatus = AccountStatus.Active

            });
            b.OwnsOne(e => e.User).HasData(new
            {
                AccountId = "37846734-172e-4149-8cec-6f43d1eb3f60",
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                AuthID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Name = "Raas Masood",
                ProfilePicUrl = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50"
            });
        });

    }
}
```

i dont want the Navigation Property "User" to be loaded unless i use "Include". but it is automatically loading. in my Startup i have configuration like this .

```
       services.AddDbContext<BBBankContext>(
b => b.UseSqlServer(connection)
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies(false)  //Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies -Version 3.1.1

        );
```

and the entities look like this

```
    public class Account : BaseEntity
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountTitle { get; set; }
    public double CurrentBalance { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public AccountStatus AccountStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
public enum AccountStatus
{
    Active = 0,
    InActive = 1
}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string AuthID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicUrl { get; set; }
}

 public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

since lazy loading is set to false. i am expecting "user" to be null

Comment: Lazy Loading means that the navigation properties will be loaded automatically as soon as they are called. If you want to use "Include" you have to use eager loading instead of lazy loading

Comment: so i set UseLazyLoadingProxies(false) which means that when i load the navigation property should not load. but it is loading.

Comment: i just updated the question with image. since lazy loading is set to false. i am expecting "user" to be null

Comment: Try to add the user data like this: `modelBuilder.Entity<User>(b =>
        {
            b.HasData(new User
            {
                AccountId = "37846734-172e-4149-8cec-6f43d1eb3f60",
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                AuthID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Name = "Raas Masood",
                ProfilePicUrl = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50"
            })`

Comment: now when i ran the User was null however when i included User "  return await DbSet.Include("User").ToListAsync();" it was still null.

DbSet is set to _context<Account>()

Comment: Did you configure the 1:n relationship between account and user? https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: so i just added "  modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasOne(p => p.User);" on the first line of OnModelCreating. is that it ?

Comment: is it 1:n or 1:1?

Comment: it is 1:1 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: `modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasOne(a => a.User)
            .WithOne(u => u.Account)
            .HasForeignKey<Account>(a => a.UserId);`

Comment: as of now User doest not have Account but Account have User. does this means i should add Account to User as well ? wont it be against the philosophy of code first ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207486/discussion-between-julida-and-raas-masood).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [Microsoft EF Core instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#other-relationship-patterns) here is the way I'd do it (I additionally changed the Key property type to Guid):

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Account : BaseEntity
    {
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string AccountTitle { get; set; }
        public double CurrentBalance { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public AccountStatus AccountStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    }

public class User : BaseEntity
    {
        public string AuthID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePicUrl { get; set; }
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    }

public enum AccountStatus
    {
        Active = 0,
        InActive = 1
    }

public class BBBankContext : DbContext
    {
        public BBBankContext(DbContextOptions<BBBankContext> options)
        : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>(b =>
            {
                b.HasData(new Account
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("37846734-172e-4149-8cec-6f43d1eb3f60"),
                    AccountNumber = "0001-1001",
                    AccountTitle = "Raas Masood",
                    CurrentBalance = 2342.34,
                    Email = "raasmasood@hotmail.com",
                    PhoneNumber = "6096647000",
                    AccountStatus = AccountStatus.Active,
                    UserId = Guid.Parse("24ce7f8a-cbeb-4b33-8a3d-952830b92d04")
                });

                b.HasOne(a => a.User)
                    .WithOne(u => u.Account)
                    .HasForeignKey<Account>(a => a.UserId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>(b =>
            {
                b.HasData(new User
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("24ce7f8a-cbeb-4b33-8a3d-952830b92d04"),
                    AuthID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Name = "Raas Masood",
                    ProfilePicUrl = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50"
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

You can find the working repository [at GitHub](https://github.com/JulidaRocks/EF_Core_1_1)

Comment: "A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32."

looks like some cyclic stuff is happening in the model structure.

Comment: I created a github repository. Works like a charm ;-) I linked it for you in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Even with lazy loading disabled, if a DbContext is already tracking an entity that you reference, that reference will be populated automatically.

For example, if I have 2 Parent records each containing a Child record:

Parent 1 => Child 1

Parent 2 => Child 2

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    var junk = context.Parents.Single(x => x.ParentId == 2);

    var children = context.Children.ToList();
    Assert.IsNull(children.Single(x => x.ChildId == 1).Parent);
    Assert.IsNotNull(children.Single(x => x.ChildId == 2).Parent);
}
```

This is a very crude example of the behaviour, but `junk` represents the dbContext having loaded and tracking Parent ID#2. Over the life of a DbContext, this can occur anywhere prior to our call, especially where the lifetime scope is over the entire request.  When we later go to retrieve our Children, and assuming that lazy loading is turned off and we are not eager loading their parents, you will find that Child ID #1's parent reference will be #null, but the DbContext will associate Parent #2 with Child #2. When the context populates the Child #2 reference it sees the association to parent and wants Parent ID #2, it's local tracking cache knows about Parent #2, so the reference is populated automatically.

If the `junk` line was instead:

```
var junk = context.Parents.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.ParentId == 2);
```

then Child #2's Parent reference would have been #null as well since the DbContext would not be tracking that parent reference.

This can lead to all kinds of quirky behaviour as applications mature and new code is introduced or re-factored. All it takes is someone to add an `AsNoTracking()` as a "performance optimization" and some behaviour that previously had a reference to something has now broken.

As a general rule to avoid complications, my recommendation is to never return Entities beyond the scope of the DbContext that spawned them, and instead rely on ViewModels or DTOs to represent the data you want to pass to a view or return to an API consumer rather than trying to selectively populate entities for this purpose. An entity should always reflect a complete data state, either by having all of its data populated, or all data accessible (via proxies).  When incomplete entities get passed around, eventually they make their way into methods that expect complete entities (based on the method signature) and this leads to problems when data is assumed to be complete but the source of that entity left stuff out.

Comment: In that case OData can serve the purpose. We can simply return IQueryable collection and rest of the magic will be done by oData on client side. We can select and include and query everything in oData Query strings. But i get what you are saying as well. I was just trying to focus on query optimization so that i database to api is a light trip.